# Как в файле txt прочитать последнюю строчку? Есть ли встроенные методы Java для этого?

Tags: java, строки

Как в файле txt прочитать последнюю строчку? Есть ли встроенные методы Java для этого?

Comment: Если вам был дан правильный ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, галкой  - это будет полезно для тех, кто в дальнейшем наткнется на данную тему.

Answer (score 7):

```
ReversedLinesFileReader reader = new ReversedLinesFileReader(file);
String line =  reader.readLine();
if (line != null) {
// что-то сделать 
}
```

Comment: у вас просто считается строчка и проверится на `null`, в чем смысл этого кода?

Comment: @Denis ReversedLinesFileReader  читает строки в файле (в противоположном направлении, похожие на BufferedReader, но начиная с последней строки). но еще и на null нужно проверить же, чтоб убедиться, что прочли.

Comment: не обратил внимание, признаю)

Answer (score 4):

Можно бежать по файлу до конца и оставить в строковой переменной только последнюю строку:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
String last, line;
while (null != (line = input.readLine())) {
    last = line;
}
```

Способ не самый элегантный, но всё равно работает шустро без установки сторонних библиотек - на 1.000.000 строк сработал за менее 1/3 секунды (312 милисекунд).

Comment: а если в файле 10000000 строк? (риторический вопрос, думаю, ты понял меня)

Comment: @SeniorAutomator тест на файле с 1.000.000 строк сейчас показал 312 милисекунд (меньше 1/3 секунды). Зачем без необходимости ставить стороннюю библиотеку, если и так всё работает шустро?

Comment: а если 10000 файлов размером по 80 Гб ? сторонние библиотеки нужны для того, чтобы не писать свои велосипеды

Comment: @SeniorAutomator можете провести сравнительный тест, я бы с удовольствием посмотрел на разницу по времени, сейчас нет возможности скачать Apache Common.

Comment: Если уж вы приводите метрики, то почему вы не пишете среднюю длину строки в файле? параметры вашей машины?, версию jvm?, прогретая она или нет?, что то мне подсказывает что при увеличении первого параметра ваш код будет проигрывать реализации оcнованой на RandomAcessFile

Comment: @StrangerintheQ зачем? я провёл метрику для себя, если кто хочет провести именно сравнительный тест - welcome.

Comment: прикольно, но вы уверены что померили то, что хотели? =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ нет, я же неуверенный в себе недопрограммист :)

Answer (score 4):

В библиотеке [apache-commons-io](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5) есть класс для этого:
[org.apache.commons.io.input.ReversedLinesFileReader](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReversedLinesFileReader.html)

его реализация основана на `RandomAccessFile`

```
ReversedLinesFileReader reader = new ReversedLinesFileReader(...);
String line =  reader.readLine();
```